# How to Get data from Combo Box and Input it to Text Box with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code, it is quite simple but why isn't it working?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=”text/javascript“>
            function Expedisi() 
            {
                var x=document.getElementById("cmb");//this the script for get data combo box
                var y = document.getElementById("txt");
                getCmb = x.value; 
                y.value = getCmb;
                alert(x);
            }
    </head>  
    <body>
        <select name="JENIS" id="cmb" data-role="slider" onChange="Expedisi()">
            <option value="Suplier">Sup</option>
            <option value="Expedisi">Exp</option>//if i pick one of this                          the value will be input on text box
        </select> 

        <input type="text" name="BKIRIM" id="txt" value=""> //this the destination value
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone Helpme? because this script is not run?

Thanks

Comment: Have you check if you have javascript enabled on your browser? What browser are you using?

Comment: You didn't close the `script` tag

Comment: What's with the crazy quotes in `type=”text/javascript“`

Comment: @Musa Thanks, it Work, the quote is the problems, its inaccurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need getCmb, and you don't need to declare an extra element.

Use this instead:

```
<html>
      <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
             function Expedisi(t) 
             {
                var y=document.getElementById("txt");
                y.value = t.value;
              }
        </script>
      </head>  
   <body>

   <select name="JENIS" id="cmb" data-role="slider" onChange="Expedisi(this);">
                          <option value="Suplier">Sup</option>
                          <option value="Expedisi">Exp</option>
    </select> 

     <input type="text" name="BKIRIM" id="txt" value=""/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If the form controls are put in a form, you can do `t.form.BKIRIM.value = t.value;`. And there is no need for the XML-style tags, the closing '/' is simply ignored.

Comment: @Patrick Im Using Adobe Dreamweaver CS3., any problem with that?

Comment: OK, I've create a [fiddle with your code here](http://jsfiddle.net/et2Dp/), test it, and copy and paste the code from the `html` textarea into dreamweaver, and see if it works.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks , your script is work after I change the Quote

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working for me. Try it here. http://jsfiddle.net/DLs7j/
That is the same exact code as yours. Copy, pasted.

Best

Comment: Maybe because I use the jquery mobile.., can you tell me the solution script for still run in jquery mobile?

Comment: Now that is a different question. You should have been clear on your question so others can help you out quickly. May I suggest you open a new question for that so the JQM experts here can contribute.

JQM renders page differently, that said. Some js may not supported as.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the quotes around the script type tag.
You are current using the ”” instead of ""; so change  ”text/javascript” to "text/javascript".